# Convert a large nested list containing a list of 5 elements containg character vectors of different length into a dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse, rvest, purrr

I have a large list containing data from the following web-scraping function. I want to have these list transformed into a data.frame with column names equal the node names. How can I do this most efficiently?

The code to generate the large list (may take a while):

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)

### Scraper

scraper <- function(pages){ #pages = 1200 should be enough to cover the year
bribe <- read_html(paste("http://ipaidabribe.com/reports/paid?page", pages, sep = "=")) 
f <- compose(html_text,html_nodes)
all.nodes <- c(".paid-amount span", ".date", ".location", ".transaction a", ".body-copy-lg")
map_df(all.nodes, ~f(bribe, .x))
}
#pages <- seq(10, 1300, by = 10)
#For MWE
pages <- seq(10, 30, by = 10)
bribe.info <- map(pages,~scraper(.x))
```

Access to the complete object : https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/841630/bribe.RData

Comment: Its nice of you to warn us this might take a while (how long? minutes? hours?) but it would be better if you could create a minimal example or a saved version of the data we can download.

Comment: As a reproducible example, you can change the `seq` to a smaller one

Comment: That is a good idea. I will add this to the post. Thanks.

Comment: YOur code is giving errors for me `bribe.info <- map_df(pages,~scraper(.x))
Error: Argument 1 must have names
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: I changed the problematic line. Does anyone might be able to fix the original transformation problem?

Comment: Hi mugdi, you might want to provide a smaller reproducible example. This way it's easier for you to describe the problem and for us to help you with it. See https://www.tidyverse.org/help/ for a small guide in creating nice reprexes!

Comment: Hey @PeterH., I thought I did so by reducing the amount of scraped pages to 3 instead of 130. This code to run should not take more than a couple of minutes. And even if this is too much, I provided the full list I need to transform into a data.frame at the end of the post. I hope thereby a MWE is provided while the whole object can still be easily retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an idea. But it still gives me an error. May anyone be able to fix this?

```
r <- bribe.info %>% 
  map_depth(2, na.omit) %>% 
  map(partial(as_tibble, .name_repair = "universal")) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "names" )
```

The error is the following :

> New names:
>   * `-> ...1
>   *` -> ...2
>   * `-> ...3
>   *` -> ...4
>   * `-> ...5
>   New names:
>   *` -> ...1
>   * `-> ...2
>   *` -> ...3
>   * `-> ...4
>   *` -> ...5
>   Error: Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, only values of length one are >recycled:
>   * Length 10: Columns `...1`, `...2`, `...3`, `...4`
>   * Length 11: Column `...5`

I can see why the problem occurs but I don't know how to fix this. In column 5 are several different vectors with different vector lengths.